# Mailchimp php integration - form field for phone numbers

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am building a basic mailchimp form using php. However I am not sure what field name to use for **phone number**s when capturing user info.

Is it supposed to be `'phone_number' => $phone,` or `'pnumber' => $phone` ?

I've looked everywhere for days, and no one talks about it, not even in the mailchimp documentation.

Here is what I mean.

```
// member information
    $json = json_encode([
        'email_address' => $email,
        'status'        => 'subscribed',
        'phone_number' => $phone,
         // is it supposed to be phone_number???
    ]);
```

This is my input fields for my form

```
        <input type="name" placeholder="First Name" required name="fname">
        <input type="name" placeholder="Last Name" required  name="lname">
        <input type="Email" placeholder="Email" required name="email">
        <input type="name" placeholder="Contact Number" name="phone">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are capturing data and want to add it to a list on MailChimp. There are no standard fields like this on MailChimp. The only one field that is required is email address so even your payload with first name and last name will not work if you are trying to POST a new member to a list. The first name and last name with the tags FNAME and LNAME come as standard when you create a new list but there is no requirement to keep them in a list.

When you post the data you need an email address, the status and an array of merge variables. So at its simplest (using your data), the json would be (I will let you convert it to the language of your choice):

```
{     
  "email_address": "test@example.com",   
  "status": "subscribed",  
  "merge_fields": {
    "FNAME": "first",
    "LNAME": "last",
    "PHONE": "phone"
  }
}
```

Of course the phone tag would depend on how it is set up on your list

Check the MailChimp documentation here for more information: http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/

Comment: @zeiddevn thanks a mate! very useful information. Your suggestion of "merge_fields" needing to contain the PHONE field makes perfect sense and it works great! THANKS